# phpunit tutorial is not showing the correct number of assertions

Tags: unit-testing, testing, phpunit, backend

I'm currently doing this tutorial

https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-2-assertions-writing-a-useful-test-and-dataprovider/

After I create the phpunit test

```
<?php

namespace phpUnitTutorial\Test;

class URLTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
//
}
```

I run it and predictably, I get an error.  However, I should be getting
Tests: 2 and Assertions: 1   instead, I'm getting 1 test and 0 assertions.

Comment: The tutorial uses phpunit version 3.7.14 . Which version are you using on your machine ? ```phpunit --version``` or ```php phpunit-x.y.z.phar --version``` should give you the output for your version

Comment: There is no assertion in your test-case. You should also see an error showing that the test contains no assertions.